# Drupal 7 module jquery script UNDEFINED issue

Tags: jquery, module, drupal-7

I have a suspicion this will be a fairly simple issue to resolve but I'm out of ideas.

My module uses the **drupal_add_js** function to load a javascript but all my attempts to access the html elements don't work.

I'm trying the following code without success:

```
(function ($) {
    console.log('CHECKING: ' + jQuery('div.view-id-events_listings').css());
})(jQuery);
```

I keep getting the following error:

> CHECKING: undefined

I have tried using the **$** symbol instead of **jQuery** but with no difference.

Would appreciate some advice on what I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(function ($) {
  Drupal.behaviors.MODULE_NAME = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      console.log('CHECKING: ' + $('div.view-id-events_listings').css());
    }
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Also check whether "view-id-events_listings" class present or not.